# Multiview: clear state of the second view when getting back to the first view in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, sdk

I am writing a program with 2 views. From the mainview, which is the FirstView, I move to the second view by:

```
-(IBAction)switchToSecondView:(id)sender{

    SecondViewController *screen=[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];
}
```

In the Second View, I have a button and a Label. The SecondView is a simple activity with a Label starting with value 0. Clicking a button each time results in increment of Label by 1. So  what I do with the SecondView is I click the button to set the new value of the Label to 5.

I then move back to the FirstView by calling:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

End then, I come back to the Second View again, but the value of Label is still 5, this means that the state of the SecondView is not clear.

Is there anyway to clear ALL the state of Second View when leaving? Thanks

Comment: Exactly what do you have on your second view? UITextfields etc?

Comment: @nicktones: I just added something to my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you say text view do you mean UILabel?

If so then this will achieve what you are after -

```
    -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    nameOfUILabel.text = @"";
    [navController viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

This sets the text value of UILabel to a blank string

Comment: i just changed to label, sorry mistaken with Android SDK. But what if I have many other states? I want to reset all together

Comment: Just add lines between the curly brackets. Same as the one in the example but for your other objects